# Javascript POST function doesn't trigger with webpack and symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I'm trying to gather information from a form and then send a POST request, it's as simple as that.

The problem is that this one never sends (I'm sure it doesn't, I checked with development tools) and I can't understand why. Moreover, it works fine in Safari and Chrome. This only happens while using Firefox.
If I place it at the top of the main function (with fake data, just to check if it sends), it will send but I first need to process data in order to get all I need.

If you have any idea why this post function only triggers before the "for" loop and not after it, you'll be my savior.

I'm using Symfony and this file is automatically created while building assets. However I'm trying to handle it directly for testing purposes.

```
           e("#team_form").submit(function() {
                for (e(".selectPlayer").each(function() {
                    a = e(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-id"), t.push(a), void 0 == n && (n = e(this).find("option:selected").attr("team-data"))
                }); t.length < 16;) t.push(null);
                var u = e("#adverse").val();
                e.post("sendToCollect", {
                    adverse: u,
                    team: n,
                    player1: t[0],
                    player2: t[1],
                    player3: t[2],
                    player4: t[3],
                    player5: t[4],
                    player6: t[5],
                    player7: t[6],
                    player8: t[7],
                    player9: t[8],
                    player10: t[9],
                    player11: t[10],
                    player12: t[11],
                    player13: t[12],
                    player14: t[13],
                    player15: t[14],
                    player16: t[15]
                })
            }),
```

Comment: You need to prevent the browser default form submit process. Also check console for errors

Comment: when you click the button which gonna make the submit event.. the page is auto-refresing ? just do what @charlietfl tip to you, so.. inside the callback of .submit pass the default paramater called event which have a method preventDefault();
.submit(function(event) {event.preventDefault();  /*your code*/ })

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I'm greatful, it worked !